# Form values using cfloop index

Tags: sql-server, forms, coldfusion, cfloop

I'm using a cfloop to create a form and populate text fields with values from a database query. I also created an array. It is returning "depthinput1", "deptinput2", and so on in the input boxes, instead of the values in the database fields. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<cfloop index="i" from="0" to="#totalsegment-1#">
    <cfloop query="flowQy" startrow="1" endrow="#totalsegment-1#">

    <cfset newarray =ArrayNew(1)>
    <cfset depthinput=structNew()>
    <cfset depthinput[i] = "depthinput" & i>
    <cfset arrayAppend(newarray, depthinput)>
    <cfinput name="depthinput#i#"  tabindex="#((i+1)*2)-1#" type="text"  onfocus="this.value='';findTotal();" size="10" onblur="findTotal();" value='#depthinput[i]#'  id="depthinput#i#"></cfinput></br>

    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

[image: Image of Form]

Comment: 1.) Avoid `<cfinput>` 2.) do a dump of `newarray` to confirm that you are getting what you want. 3.) `</br>` is not a thing. 4.) Can you provide a screenshot of what this looks like? 5.) no need to use startrow on a query 6.) Look up how to use `<cfoutput>`

Comment: Which line of code is supposed to reference a value from the query?

Comment: <cfinput name="depthinput#i#"  tabindex="#((i+1)*2)-1#" type="text"  onfocus="this.value='';findTotal();" size="10" onblur="findTotal();" value='#depthinput[i]#'  id="depthinput#i#"></cfinput></br>

Comment: value='#depthinput[i]#'

Comment: I added an image of the form.

Comment: Are you saying the *query* is what contains the values of "depthinput1", "depthinput2", etc... that you're trying to display?

Comment: Why are there two loops? As it stands you are going to have inputs with the same name/ids.

Comment: Yes. If I type in the value=‘depthinput1’ it displays the value from the table. I do need to keep it dynamic as the it can loop to 32 input boxes in some cases.

Comment: Pretty sure `depthinput[i]` should be set to a value of `flowQy.something`. Your data is in flowQy right? You are making `depthinput[i]` the value of "depthinput" & i, which is exactly what is output.

Comment: Leeish- tried that and the error says something like I’m mixing complex with simple expressions.

Comment: What does your query and your data look like? This could probably be reached a bit easier through your query itself. Then all you'd need is a simple loop over your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a data dump, it's difficult to tell how the data is actually stored, which makes the question a little confusing.

Are "depthinput1", "depthinput2" the names of columns in the query?

```
RecordID | DepthInput1 | DepthInput2 | ... | DepthInputN
1        |     35.5    | 86.2        | ... |    14.6
```

... OR are the "depthInput" values actually stored in separate rows ?

```
RecordID | DepthInput 
1        |    35.5    
2        |    86.2 
....
86       |    14.6
```

If they're query columns, consider restructuring the database table. Similar column names like "thing1", "thing2", ... are usually an indicator the data should be stored in separate rows (like above). If you really can't change the structure, use associative array notation to access the query columns dynamically, `queryName["columnName"][rowNumber]#`:

```
<cfoutput query="flowQy">
   <!--- determines which columns to display:  -->
   <cfloop from="0" to="#totalSegment#" index="i">
    <input name="depthInput#i#" value="#flowQy['depthInput'& i+1][flowQy.currentRow]#"><br>
   </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

If the values are actually stored in separate rows, just loop through the query and use `queryName.currentRow` as an index.

```
<cfoutput query="flowQy">
    <input name="depthInput#flowQy.currentRow-1#" 
        value="#flowQy.depthInput#"><br>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something more like:

```
<cfoutput query="flowQy">
 <input name="depthinput#currentRow#" type="text" ... value="#somecolumninQuery#" id="depthinput#currentRow#" />
</cfoutput>
```

It's really hard to tell what your code is even attempting to do or exactly where the data is that you are trying to reference.

Comment: Agreed. @JDav - It would much easier to help if you could do a `cfdump` of the query results and post a screen shot.